Is it possible to generate lightning address / invoice that can be used multiple times?
I'm planning to attend art exhibition, displaying some of my pieces, it's actually for the  coming soon.
I can easily print QR code with my on-chain BTC address.
I would like to print QR code with my lightning address to receive SATS.
Is it possible?
To have a printed out QR code with to receive SATS on lightning would be a dream.
Workaround: use a URL shortening service, that redirects QR code to something that generates invoice on the fly...

Yes, it's possible, you can use a LNURL or even a LN address.
In my case, I would encode my LN address in a QRCode (bordalix@getalby.com) and that should work. When a LN reads an address like this (looks like an email address) it goes to the domain getalby.com and asks for an invoice for the user bordalix. It then pays the invoice.
Know more about LN addresses on https://lightningaddress.com/
